# Troubleshooting foreign key dependency error when setting up new MariaDB replica

Tags: replication, backup, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

**Question:** Does anyone have advice on what I can do to successfully get this new replica set up and replicating from our production server just like the old replica?

---

**Details:**

I am trying to set up a new MariaDB replica from an existing replica so that we do not have to take the production server down to create the new replica. Here is the procedure I go through to import the DB to the new host.

1. On the current replica: `MariaDB> STOP SLAVE;`
2. On the current replica: `$ /usr/bin/mysql -u $USER -p $PASS -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G' > slave_status.txt`
3. On the new replica: `$ /usr/bin/mysqldump --add-drop-database --all-databases -u $USER -p $PASS -h $CURRENT_REPLICA --flush-privileges | /usr/bin/mysql -u root`
4. On the current replica: Make sure that the `MariaDB> SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G` output is still the same as it was in `slave_status.txt`
5. Grab the `Relay_Master_Log_File`, `Master_Host`, `Master_User`, and `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` values from `slave_status.txt`
6. On the new replica: `MariaDB> CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='$Master_Host', MASTER_USER='$Master_User', MASTER_PASSWORD='$Master_Password', MASTER_LOG_FILE='$Relay_Master_Log_File', MASTER_LOG_POS=$Exec_Master_Log_Pos;`
7. On the new replica: `MariaDB> SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G` and compare to `slave_status.txt`... All looks good
8. On the new replica: `MariaDB> START SLAVE;`

Once the replication has been running for a little bit, usually a few minutes, I get error #1451 below

> Error 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ('$DATABASE'.'$TABLE', CONSTRAINT '$TABLE_ibfk_3' FOREIGN KEY ('$KEY') REFERENCES '$OTHER_TABLE' ('$OTHER_TABLE_KEY') ON UPDATE CASCADE)' on query. Default database: '$DATABASE'. Query: 'DELETE FROM $OTHER_TABLE WHERE $OTHER_TABLE_KEY in (#########, #########, #########, #########, #########, ...

There are multiple databases hosted in this MariaDB instance and every time I have done this process it is the same database that runs into this foreign key dependency error. The current replica has been running for years without a problem. I have tried the same MariaDB version (10.1.12) on the new host as the old host, as well as a newer version (10.4.17) on the new host. The database which results in this error is using InnoDB.

I have verified that `/etc/my.cnf` and `/etc/my.cnf.d/*` are the same except for the server ID for the two replicas. One of the first times I ran through this process I copy-pasted the failed command from the error log and it ran without a problem, I then set the `Skip_Counter` to 1 and it continued for a while and got the same error. I did this 5 times before giving up on that as a method to proceed.

If there is any other useful information I can provide, please let me know. I tried to include everything I could think of but I wouldn't be surprised if I missed something useful.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to have been some issue regarding timezones with the replicated database. I tried using mysql_tzinfo_to_sql to set up the timezone in the SQL database but that didn't work. So I moved on to trying docker and setting up the timezone at the image level and now I have the replication fully functioning.